# How to crawl google to find meaning of a particular text in my site?

Tags: php, web

I wish to incorporate following feature in my site.When a user selects a particular text,he should be able to see a pop up which shows the meaning of the selected text?How can this be accomplished in php?In other words,how can we use google (may be crawl it somehow) to find the meaning of the selected text?

Comment: I recommend you to look for some dictionary JSON API.

Answer (score 1):

Scraping Google, or any site for that matter, can be unreliable if they ever decide to change formatting of their output data for search results. I would recommend using the Wikipedia API (http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API) to provide you with the definitions. The API documentation for php can be found here: http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php